# API error during Terraform refresh when attempting to deploy schemas

Tags: terraform, confluent-schema-registry

We have two Terraform modules in our code base. The first module deploys out a Confluent Kafka cluster as well as a schema registry. The second deploys out topics and schemas. We have it split up this way as we've decided on a microservices approach for our architecture and would like to deploy out schemas and topics independently.

Due to this approach, we're storing various secrets in a key vault, such as the cluster/schema id, rest endpoint, api key, and api secret. Then in the topics/schemas module we pull down those secrets from the key vault and include those when creating the resources.

The issue we're running into is when we tear down our cluster and schema registry, and then re-deploy it. We then attempt to re-deploy schemas and we're running into this error when Terraform is refreshing state during the plan phase:

**Error: error reading Schema: error reading Schema "old-schema-registry-id/subject-name/latest": error loading the latest Schema: error loading the latest Schema: 404 Not Found: Subject 'subject-name' not found.**

It seems like the issue is that Terraform is attempting to refresh the state using the old schema registry id, instead of the new value that we're pulling down from the key vault. We initially ran into this with topics, but after adding this to the provider block that solved this:

```
provider "confluent" {
  kafka_id            = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.cluster_id.value
  kafka_rest_endpoint = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.cluster_rest_endpoint.value
  kafka_api_key       = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.cluster_key.value
  kafka_api_secret    = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.cluster_secret.value
}
```

We've attempted doing the same thing for the schema registry secrets:

```
provider "confluent" {
  kafka_id            = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.cluster_id.value
  kafka_rest_endpoint = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.cluster_rest_endpoint.value
  kafka_api_key       = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.cluster_key.value
  kafka_api_secret    = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.cluster_secret.value

  schema_registry_id            = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.schema_registry_id.value
  schema_registry_rest_endpoint = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.schema_registry_rest_endpoint.value
  schema_registry_api_key       = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.schema_registry_api_key.value
  schema_registry_api_secret    = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.schema_registry_api_secret.value
}
```

However we're still facing the 404 subject not found error. Anyone have any ideas on what we can try next?